# ArcGIS Pro 2.0.1 crashes 100% of the time when closing panels

Tags: installation, arcgis-pro

I just installed it last night. I can reproduce this problem 100% of the time with the symbology panel and the attribute table panel (and sometimes happens when I open them too).

Only happens when in DirectX mode, it works perfectly in OpenGL but doesn't render as nicely.

I updated my graphics drivers and it didn't help. Any thoughts? It's pretty unusable right now.

Comment: Do you have Windows localized to another language such as Arabic, if so try putting it back to US English to see if that makes a difference?

Comment: Do you receive any error message?

Comment: I don't have windows localized to another language. Also, no error message. I don't know if it's as much of a crash as it is it completely stops responding and hangs. I didn't turn on the reporting to ESRI, is there a way to turn it on after installation?

Comment: I am pretty much convinced that it has something to do with DirectX. None of these problems appear in OpenGL. I would just use OpenGL, but it isn't rendering 3D layers correctly. That problem doesn't happen in DirectX.

Comment: https://twitter.com/inertcatnip/status/1062753119304482816?s=21